# How are values stored in array methods?

Tags: java

I'm not sure what the differences between the two code samples below are. (The first sample uses Picture.java from the [standard library](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/Picture.java.html)):

---

```
//chooses a photo from your computer and reads RGB values from it
Picture mypic = new Picture(FileChooser.pickAFile());
Pixel pixelArray [] = mypic.getPixels();
pixelArray[0].setRed(255);
Pixel currentPixel = pixelArray[0];
currentPixel.setRed(0);
pixelArray[0].getRed()
```

**output: 0** <== changes in variable currentPixel changes the value in pixelArray[0] without explicit declaration.

---

```
int array[] = new int[4];
array[0] = 1;
int firstElement = array[0];
firstElement = 9;
array[0]
```

**output: 1** <== changes in variable firstElement does not change the value in array[0]

---

Why does the first code sample output 0 instead of 255, and why does the second code sample output 1 instead of 9?

Comment: The second is operating on a primitive value, the first on a *reference* type.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I sort of understand what you're saying, but not enough to point out the difference in code if I were asked to.

Does it have to do with the Pixel class and the fact that I have to use methods on it?

Comment: Basically yes. An `int` is a fixed 32-bit quantity, a reference type is any `Object` (or sub-class, including `Pixel`).

Comment: While you say `Picture` is from the "standard library", the link you point to defines a `Picture` class that doesn't define `getPixels`.  So you seem to be using a different `Picture` class.

Comment: ok, so just for comparison: how would I store a value in currentPixel and change it without affecting pixelArray[]?

Comment: @ajb it comes from an imported library referenced in Picture.java. I'm not sure which, but it was just there for context. I'm having trouble understanding the general concept.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  I assume there's something at the top of your source that says `import some.package.name.Picture`; what is the package name?

Comment: "how would I store a value..."  Somehow you have to make a copy of a `Pixel`, but the `Pixel` class itself would have to provide the mechanisms that allow you to do that, and I'd have to see what methods/constructors `Pixel` provides before figuring out how to make a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`currentPixel` is a reference to `pixelArray[0]`, not a copy (ie. they point to the same object). On the other hand, `firstElement` is a copy of `array[0]`. In most cases when you assign an object to a variable, it will be a reference rather than a copy. If you want a new `Pixel` you will have to create one by calling the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is passing the object around, an instance of Pixel. This is being done under the covers by using the address of the object in memory. Therefore anything you do to the object, is done to the object, and not a copy of the object. This is called 'by reference'.

In the second example int firstElement = array[0]; is taking the value at the memory location of array[0] and copying it to your new memory location firstElement. The two are not the same location in memory so when you update firstElement you are NOT updating array[0]. This is called 'by value'.

EDIT:

To answer your question: There is no such thing as an array method.

What you are getting is an 'Array offset'.

An array is a linear chunk of memory. It is split into equal sizes to handle the values that you ask it to (4 bytes for 32-bit Integer, 2 bytes for a 16-bit integer, 1 byte for a char, etc...). Addresses used to be 32-bit, now 64-bit. So when referencing objects array[0] is the base of the memory chunk array[1] is the base + sizeof(int), and so on.

Comment: Okay, so let's see if I'm understanding this clearly...

the new Picture is an instance, and the instance variables referring to Picture are mypic, pixelArray, and currentPixel. 

So anything that is associated with the Picture instance is a reference?

(I'm not sure how pixelArray and currentPixel are instances and not instance variables)